# Mistakes in my mips code to return multiples of X where X is 1, 2,4, 8, 16 and such

Tags: assembly, mips

```
# arrayCount.asm
  .data 
arrayA: .word 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 
count:  .word 6         

  .text
main:
    # code to setup the variable mappings
    la $t0, arrayA
    la $t1, count

    # code for reading in the user value X
    li $v0, 5
    move $t3, $v0
    syscall

    # code for counting multiples of X in arrayA
    addi $t4, $zero, 0 #number
start:
    beq $t1, $zero, exit

    lw $t6, 0($t0)
    and $t5, $t3, $t6
    addi, $t1, $t1, -1
    la $t0, 4($t0)
    beq $t5, $zero, update 
    j start

update:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    j start

    # code for printing result
exit:
    li $v0, 1
    la $a0, number
    syscall

    # code for terminating program
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I keep getting an exception error what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to post the full error messge you're getting, and point out which line of code it refers to.

Comment: You're going to want `sll` to create a power of 2.  Include the error message to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There are quite few errors

1. You use `la $t1, count` which load the address of the count, but not
   the value of it (6).
2. You try to save the return of the user input reading before it is even happened.
3. On `exit` you try to load `number` symbol, but that is not exists.

Also your algorithm does not make that much sense, but you are not too clear about what your goal so I can not fix it.

The code with the fixes:

```
# arrayCount.asm
  .data 
arrayA: .word 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 
count:  .word 6         

  .text
main:
    # code to setup the variable mappings
    la $t0, arrayA
    lw $t1, count    # fix #1

    # code for reading in the user value X
    li $v0, 5
    syscall    # fix #2
    move $t3, $v0

    # code for counting multiples of X in arrayA
    addi $t4, $zero, 0 #number
start:
    beq $t1, $zero, exit

    lw $t6, 0($t0)
    and $t5, $t3, $t6
    addi, $t1, $t1, -1
    la $t0, 4($t0)
    beq $t5, $zero, update 
    j start

update:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    j start

    # code for printing result
exit:
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t4    # fix #3
    syscall

    # code for terminating program
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall
```